# How to Like/Unlike list item using CSOM in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom

This is a sample code for like/unlike list Item using SSOM.

```
private void forItem(SPList list, SPWeb web, string opp)
    {
        int lastUserCount;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPQuery queryItem = new SPQuery();
        queryItem.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + itemTitle.Text + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(queryItem);
        SPListItem item = items[0];
        string likedBys = item["Liked By"] == null ? string.Empty : item["Liked By"].ToString();
        SPFieldUserValueCollection likedBy = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, likedBys);
        lastUserCount = likedBy.Count == 0 ? 1 : likedBy.Count;  





        switch (opp)
            {
                case "like":
                    {
                        for (int i = lastUserCount; i <= lastUserCount + 50; i++)
                        {
                            string userName = "Users" + i.ToString();
                            SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("SHAREPOINT\\" + userName);
                            SPFieldUserValue newUser = new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name);



                            if (likedBy.ToString().Contains(user.Name.ToString()) == false)
                            {
                                likedBy.Add(newUser);
                                int NoOfLikes = likedBy.Count;
                                item["LikesCount"] = NoOfLikes;
                                item["Liked By"] = likedBy;
                                display.Text = user.Name + " has like this item";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                display.Text = user.Name + " already liked this item";
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case "unlike":
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i < 700; i++)
                        {
                            string userName = "Users" + i.ToString();
                            SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("SHAREPOINT\\" + userName);
                            SPFieldUserValue newUser = new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name);

                            if (likedBy.ToString().Contains(user.Name.ToString()) == true)
                            {
                                int index = ForIndex(likedBy, newUser);
                                likedBy.RemoveAt(index);
                                int NoOfLikes = likedBy.Count;
                                item["LikesCount"] = NoOfLikes;
                                item["Liked By"] = likedBy;
                                display.Text = user.Name + " has unlike this item";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                display.Text = user.Name + " already Unliked liked this item";
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case "show":
                    display.Text = item["Liked By"] == null ? " No User Likes  item" : "This Item is liked by <br>" + likedBys;
                    break;
            }
            item.SystemUpdate();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }

    int ForIndex(SPFieldUserValueCollection likedBy, SPFieldUserValue newUser)
    {
        int returnIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < likedBy.Count; i++)
        {
            if (newUser.ToString() == likedBy[i].ToString())
            {
                returnIndex = i;
                return returnIndex;
            }
        }
        return returnIndex = likedBy.Count;
    }
```

But I need to do this with CSOM, how can I do that?

Comment: You need to clarify your problem

Comment: I want the code for like/unlike any Custom list Item using CSOM @RobertLindgren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a relevant answer related to this question.

```
class LikeOrUnlikeItem
{
    public void LikeByUser(ClientContext clientContext, Web web, List list, User user, ListItem item)
    {
        bool hasLiked = false;

        FieldUserValue[] fieldUserValue = (FieldUserValue[])item["LikedBy"];
        List<FieldUserValue> newFieldUsers = new List<FieldUserValue>();
        if (fieldUserValue != null && fieldUserValue.Length > 0)
            foreach (FieldUserValue likedFieldUser in fieldUserValue)
                if (likedFieldUser.LookupValue == user.Title)
                    hasLiked = true;

        if (!hasLiked)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.Title + " Not liked this item");
            LikeItemOrSkip(item, fieldUserValue, newFieldUsers, user);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.Title + " Already liked this item");
            UnlikeItemOrSkip(item, fieldUserValue, newFieldUsers, user);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }



    private void LikeItemOrSkip(ListItem item,FieldUserValue[] fieldUserValue, List<FieldUserValue> newFieldUsers,User user)
    {
        string userEnteredValue;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You want to like or Skip");
            userEnteredValue = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userEnteredValue == "Like" || userEnteredValue == "like")
            {
                if (fieldUserValue != null)
                    foreach (FieldUserValue likedFieldUser in fieldUserValue)
                        newFieldUsers.Add(likedFieldUser);
                newFieldUsers.Add(FieldUserValue.FromUser(user.LoginName));
                item["LikedBy"] = newFieldUsers;
                item["LikesCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(item["LikesCount"]) + 1;
                item.Update();
                Console.WriteLine(user.Title + " like this item ");
            }
            else if (userEnteredValue != "" && userEnteredValue != "skip")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Valid Input!!");
            }
        } while (userEnteredValue != "Like" && userEnteredValue != "like" && userEnteredValue != "" && userEnteredValue != "skip");
    }


    private void UnlikeItemOrSkip(ListItem item, FieldUserValue[] fieldUserValue, List<FieldUserValue> newFieldUsers, User user)
    {
            string userEnteredValue = Console.ReadLine();
         do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("You want to Unlike or Skip");
            if (userEnteredValue == "Unlike" || userEnteredValue == "unlike")
            {
                if (fieldUserValue != null)
                    foreach (FieldUserValue likedFieldUser in fieldUserValue)
                        if (likedFieldUser.LookupValue != user.Title)
                            newFieldUsers.Add(likedFieldUser);
                item["LikedBy"] = newFieldUsers;
                item["LikesCount"] = Convert.ToInt32(item["LikesCount"]) - 1;
                item.Update();
                Console.WriteLine(user.Title + " Unlike this item ");
            }
            else { }
         } while (userEnteredValue != "UnLike" && userEnteredValue != "unlike" && userEnteredValue != "" && userEnteredValue != "skip");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

For reference visit my blog. [Click Here.](http://arzoosoni.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-to-like-list-item-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you should **not** modify the `LikesCount` like this. There is the [`Reputation.SetLike`-method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.reputationmodel.reputation.setlike.aspx) to do so.

Having said that, there also is a `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation` class in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll` (yes, there is a namespace called *server* in a dll called *client*...).

So you should, using CSOM, be able to call:

```
public void Like(string url, string listName, int itemId, int rating)
{
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        ctx.Load(list, x => x.Id);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();


        var listId = list.Id.ToString();

        Reputation.SetLike(ctx, listId, itemId, true);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

*(Reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`, `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll`. Warning: the code was not tested...)*

**However, if you're intent on doing it the *not-intended-way*** (i.e. without using the ootb-functions and instead modifying SharePoint-internals by hand):
Do roughly the same as you did before:

```
public void Like(string url, string listName, int itemId, int rating, string userName)
{
    const string LikesCountField = "LikesCount";
    const string LikedByField = "LikedBy";

    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
    {
        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
        ctx.Load(item, 
            i => i[LikedByField], 
            i => i[LikesCountField]);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();


        var likedByFieldvalue = item[LikedByField] as FieldUserValue[];
        if(likedByFieldvalue == null)
        {
            likedByFieldvalue = new FieldUserValue[0];
        }
        var likedByList = likedByFieldvalue.ToList();
        likedByList.Add(FieldUserValue.FromUser(userName));

        item[LikedByField] = likedByList;
        item[LikesCountField] = likedByList.Count;
        item.Update();

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

*(Reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`.)*

Things to keep in mind:

- It is possible that the List has a `LastRatedOrLikedBy`-Field which should contain the user which has last rated or liked. (You probably should modify this field, too.)
- When not using `Reputation.SetLike()` likes & ratings will not appear in social-feeds

Comment: Code was useful, but can we do this without using      'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll file'. Or Is there any other way of writing this code.

Comment: @ArzooSoni: I added the CSOM-code without using `Reputation.SetLike` (i.e. without referencing Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll). You should *really* consider doing things the "proper" way, because you'll never know what SharePoint internally does apart from the obvious.